# Error en la eliminación de los valores de un arraylist antes de insertar en un spinner

Tags: android, arraylist

Estoy desarollando un juego, y en una parte el jugador "tira los dados" para sacar un valor aleatorio, y al pasar de turno el siguiente jugador solo debe poder sacar los valores superiores a este, por ejemplo si saca 10, el siguiente no podria sacar menos de 10.

```
int contBorrar = 0;

if(!valorRecibido.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

    for (int cont = 0; cont < listaValores.size(); cont++) {
        Log.d("valores", listaValores.get(cont).toString());
    if (listaValores.get(cont).getValor().equalsIgnoreCase(valorRecibido)) {
        contBorrar = cont;

        }
    }

    for (contBorrar = contBorrar+1 ; contBorrar < listaValores.size();contBorrar++){
        Log.d("BORRAR", listaValores.get(contBorrar).toString());
        listaValores.remove(contBorrar);
    }

}
```

Y aqui estan los valores de las dos listas, como veis en el segundo solo coge los impares, en vez de toda la lista ordenada.

```
D/valores: Ladrillo
           Pareja
           10
           9
           8
           7
           6
           5
D/valores: 4
D/BORRAR: 9
          7
          5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia, el problema esta en tu segundo for, ya que cuanto tu borras un elemento de una lista los index cambian, me explico:

En tu lista tienes objetos

`10,9,8,7,6,5,4`

por lo cual los index en la lista serian del

`0 = 10, 1 = 9, 2 = 8, 3 = 7 ,4 = 6 , 5 = 5, 6 = 4`

tu variable contBorrar llega como 0 antes de comenzar el segundo for, debido a tu lógica previa, entonces al iniciar el for aumentas el valor de countBorrar a 1, asta aquí se podia decir que esta bien ya que quieres borrar después del numero 10, cuando tu borras el numero 9(siguiendo tu ejemplo) de la lista los index se recorren por lo cual el 8 ya no tendría el index 2 sino el 1, el 7 el 2 etc. por eso te va borrando los impares, ya que countborrar en el siguiente ciclo es 2 por lo cual se borraría el 7 no el 8. espero me puedas comprender. te recomiendo que utilices la funcionalidad iterator para poder borrar los valores de una lista, te dejo un ejemplo:

`Iterator iterator = listaValores.iterator();
 while (iterator.hasNext()){
     String value = iterator.next().toString();
     int valueInt = Integer.parseInt(value);
     if (valueInt< Integer.parseInt(valorRecibido)){
       Log.e("valores", value);
       iterator.remove();
     }
 }`

La lista contiene valores de tipo strings por lo cual los convierto a entero para poder compararlos al numero que saco el jugador, si el numero de la lista es menor al numero del jugador lo elimina de la lista, estos son los valores que se borran de la lista con este metodo:

`valores: 9
    8
    7
    6
    5
    4`

Saludos.